# Is it possible to get single SIM card for Vienna + Prague without roaming

Tags: europe, cellphones

I will be travelling between Vienna and Prague in December. My plan is to buy local SIM card but as Vienna/Prague are very near to each other, i was wondering if any mobile operators offer combined plans for both cities.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Since roaming conditions within the EU were changed in June 2017 I don't think the linked question has a up-to-date answer. Basically the changes are: You can now use your included minutes, SMS and all (or at least some parts) of your internet data also within the EU without additional costs as long as you "mainly stay in providers home country". Since I don't have comprehensive knowledge of all different tariff options for Austrian and Czech mobile providers just a link (in German) to one Austrian provider where their tariff options are explained: https://www.hot.at/eu-roaming.html

Comment: @tallistroan kindly update the linked question with the latest information. We cannot create new questions just because the situation has changed.